# Why is Axios timing out in Chrome, Safari, and the new Microsoft Edge but not Firefox?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nginx, axios, client-server

Really weirded out by the bug here, would love any help I can get.

So its actually only one specific instance of an axios call that isn't working but I don't know why it is different to the others (as my 50 other axios calls work fine).

The error message is basically just saying the request timed out due to exceeding the timeout duration I have specified (*2000ms*) however the bug was still happening on (*5000ms*) as well so I don't think the duration set is an issue.

Also, this bug does not occur in my local environment. Only on the production environment where both the front-end and the back-end are being proxied by an NginX server.

Loading in the axios

```
import {HTTP} from './../../axios-common.js'
```

The setup file (**axios-common.js**):

```
import axios from 'axios';
import settings from './settings.js'

export const HTTP = axios.create({
  baseURL: settings.server,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${settings.token}`
  },
  timeout: 2000
})
```

The function:

```
loadData: function(){
            HTTP.get(`statetable/${this.selected}`)
            .then((res) => {

                logger.info('statetable request: ' , res)
                
                if(res.data.length != 1){
                    this.Table = res.data
                }
                else if(res.data.length == 1){
                    this.$fire({
                            title: "State Table Error",
                            html: "The state table data could not be retrieved. </br> </br> <b>Backend Error:</b> " + JSON.stringify(res.data[0], null, 4),
                            type: "error"
                        })
                        console.log()
                    EventBus.$emit('state-table', 'close')
                }
                else {
                    this.$fire({
                            title: "State Table Error",
                            html: "The state table data could not be retrieved. Cause of error unkown, check log files.",
                            type: "error"
                        })
                    EventBus.$emit('state-table', 'close')
                }
                
                
                
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
                this.$fire({
                            title: "State Table Error",
                            html: "The request to the backend timed out",
                            type: "error"
                })
                EventBus.$emit('state-table', 'close')
            })
        }
```

And now the back-end route:

```
app.get('/statetable/:schoolCode', (req,res) => {
    let schoolCode = req.params.schoolCode

    if(req.headers.authorization == settings.app_settings.token){
    dbConnections[schoolCode].query(`USE ${schoolCode}`, (err) => {
        if(err){
            log.error(`Error switching to database ${schoolCode}: `, err)
        }
        dbConnections[schoolCode].query("SELECT step_name, execute, priority FROM state_data", (err, result) => {
            if(err){
                log.error(`Error getting statetable for ${schoolCode}: `, err)

                //we put it in an array because javascript typing is stupid and thinks a string and an object are the same thing
                //thus checking typeof does not suffice
                //so i put it into an array and then check the length of an array. A normal retrival of records will always be more than 1
                //whereas here you will always have a single entry
                let array = []
                array[0] = err
                res.send(array)
            }
            else {
                res.send(result)
            }
        })
    })
    }
    else{
        res.send("Authorization Error")
    }      
})
```

**Note:** All the failed requests appear in the **Network** tab of the browser as a 502 Gateway Error.

This timeout can be replicated in FireFox by spam requesting erroneous routes (ones that return errors) until the route that works starts timing out and also giving a 502 Bad Gateway error. Then all requests get a 502 Bad Gateway error.

I wasn't the one who setup the nginx server so if anyone knows if maybe there are load limits or something that could be causing this speak up.

Please leave a comment if I have not provided enough information/code. I really hope someone out here can help me out!!

Comment: What is the error you are getting ??

Comment: Timeout error. Due to the specified timeout threshold I have set.